# table with too many columns

Tags: tables, multi-column

Hope you are able to help me out with this predicament.

I have a requirements for a table with a few columns. As future requirements come in I am having to add to the columns. I wan to prevent the horizontal scroll. What do you all think is the best solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Stack two tables, one on top of the other. Yes, the first column (A) will be replicated in both tables but that is a small price to pay if your primary goal is to prevent horizontal scrolling.

Think about your user: you may be saving your user from data-overload. This solution may be more user-friendly as you will have to split your data into two logical groups. The user should be able to scan the two tables, and quickly decide which table to focus on.

How you organize and give titles the two tables is crucial for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you have great amounts of data (columns), that  probably don't have relationships between,  there is a way to divide it into groups with labels, that will help to get more navigation to the design and also help users to not get bored.
Try to divide the table into small tables that contain only columns with a common thing. Add label showing that thing.